# How to download Spreadsheets in odoo?

Tags: odoo, spreadsheet, document, odoo-16, odoo-17

**I am currently grappling with the technical challenge of automating the download process for spreadsheets associated with sale order lines in odoo. The objective is to streamline the workflow by automatically initiating the download when a sale order is confirmed.**
Screenshot.
https://imgur.com/8VfCGbH

**Technical Details:**

I have added new many2one field in sale.order.line where i will select document spreadsheet.

Once user Confirms the sale order i want to download all the spreadsheets on confirmation.

Please let me know if anyone has done this or anyone have idea on this.

Thank you.

Comment: image not found

Comment: Hi @farisfath25 It's screenshot of sale order only